# Best way to distinguish environment in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, environments

I am using MVC3, and I am wondering what is the best way to distinguish your environment? For instance I am thinking of adding a key to appSettings and referencing it, however in MVC3 is there a better way? I am working on 3 environments: Development, Staging, and Production.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the configuration manager and define DEBUG, TEST, RELEASE as compile time constants.  For configurations I use [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Application Project Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) and would highly recommend using them.

For example:

```
//web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=SqlServer\Sql2008;
                           Initial Catalog=MyDB.Dev;
                           Integrated Security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <add key="SomeAppSetting" 
       value="DebugValue"/>
</configuration>
```

Test transformation:

```
//web.Test.config
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=SqlServer\Sql2008;
                           Initial Catalog=MyDB.Test;
                           Integrated Security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
         xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <add key="SomeAppSetting" 
       value="TestValue"
       xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
       xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
</configuration>
```

When I change my configuration from debug to test and rebuild/deploy my app now uses the transformation update in my `web.Test.config`.  Extremely useful.

You can build different configurations using the [Configuration Manager Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  At anytime you can right click on the web.config and select *Add Config Transformations* to have Visual Studio 2010 create the transformation config files automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Web.config is probably a good place, for the MVC UI project. assuming that data layer and service layer are separated you would also have entries in those other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [web config transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx). Once you have the basis of your web.config setup you would create a transformation for your staging and production environments.

Many good examples on the net if you require more info.